# Integrate[Abs[x]^2,x] does not work

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Why does

```
Integrate[Abs[x]^2, x]
```

not return a proper result? It returns the integral itself...

Wolfram|Alpha properly returns x^3/3 + C.

See screenshot attached[image: Screenshot]

Comment: For real x, `Abs[x] == Sqrt[x^2]` then `Integrate[Abs[x]^2 /. Abs[x] -> Sqrt[x^2], x]` evaluates to `x^3/3` or use `Assuming[Element[x, Reals], Integrate[Abs[x]^2, x]]`

Comment: `Integrate[RealAbs[x]^2, x]`

Comment: Integrate[Abs[x]^2, x, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]

Comment: My habit is to use Assumptions-> instead of Assuming[{},].  It there a good reason why to prefer one over the other? @BobHanlon

Comment: @CraigCarter - `Assuming` will automatically apply the assumptions to any enclosed function that uses the option `Assumptions`. Consequently, as you are working with the code, any subsequent addition of a function like `Simplify` will automatically make use of the assumptions without any need to explicitly address the assumptions.

Comment: THX, this was very helpful, and it works now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `Abs[x]^2` of complex variable `x` is not analytic as

```
FunctionAnalytic[Abs[x]^2, x, Complexes]
```

> `False`

says. Therefore, `Abs[x]^2` has no antiderivative in the complex plane and Mathematica correctly returns the input of the `Integrate[Abs[x],x]` command.

However, Mathematica calculates

```
Integrate[Abs[x]^2, {x, 1, 3 + I}]
```

> `28/3 + (14 I)/3`

following the standard way of complex analysis. The path from `1` to `3+I` is parameterized as `2*t + 1 + I*t`, where `t` changes from `0` to `1`. Then

```
Integrate[ComplexExpand[Abs[2*t + 1 + I*t]^2]*(2+I),{t,0,1}]
```

> `28/3 + (14 I)/3`

The integral under  consideration depends on a path. For example. taking the path parameterized as `2*t^2+1+I*t`, we have

```
Integrate[Abs[2*t^2 + 1 + I*t]^2*(4*t + I), {t, 0, 1}]
```

> `29/3 + (52 I)/15`

One can check that the function `ComplexExpand[Abs[2*t + 1 + I*t]^2]*D[2*t + 1 + I*t, t]` of real variable `t` has its antiderivative

```
Integrate[ComplexExpand[Abs[2*t + 1 + I*t]^2]*D[2*t + 1 + I*t, t], t]
```

> `(2 + I) (t + 2 t^2 + (5 t^3)/3)`

and

```
((2 + I)*(t + 2 t^2 + (5 t^3)/3)) /. t -> 1 - (2 + I) (t + 2 t^2 + (5 t^3)/3) /. t -> 0
```

> `28/3 + (14 I)/3`